# Why Pandas Memory Error Using Lambda Function

Tags: pandas, memory, lambda

I am getting an error that crashes my program and i'm not sure how to solve it. The error is here:

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Au321103\.spyder-py3\ReadPostgreSQLMOSdata_vortex.py", line 79, in <module>
cdata[['year','month']] = cdata.Dates.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.strftime("%Y,%m").split(",")))

File "C:\Users\Au321103\Anaconda3\envs\Stats\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 3848, in 
apply
mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)

File "pandas\_libs\lib.pyx", line 2327, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer

MemoryError
```

The variable "cdata" has size (4359936,7) and is a df. The line that causes the memory issue is here:

```
cdata[['year','month']] = cdata.Dates.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.strftime("%Y,%m").split(",")))
```

cdata looks like this:

```
  plant_name business_name maint_region_name wind_speed_ms  \
0  BII NEE STIPA        MEXICO            Mexico          9.21   
1  BII NEE STIPA        MEXICO            Mexico         10.12   
2  BII NEE STIPA        MEXICO            Mexico         10.23   
3  BII NEE STIPA        MEXICO            Mexico         10.21   
4  BII NEE STIPA        MEXICO            Mexico         10.13   

               mos_time power_kwh       Dates  
0 2021-01-31 01:00:00+00:00   15087.0  2021-01-31  
1 2021-01-31 00:00:00+00:00   16658.0  2021-01-31  
2 2021-01-30 23:00:00+00:00   18753.3  2021-01-30  
3 2021-01-30 22:00:00+00:00   20182.6  2021-01-30  
4 2021-01-30 21:00:00+00:00   20172.9  2021-01-30
```

and...

```
cdata.columns
Out[3]: 
Index(['plant_name', 'business_name', 'maint_region_name', 'wind_speed_ms',
   'mos_time', 'power_kwh', 'Dates'],
  dtype='object')
```

I cannot understand why the memory error crashes the program on the lambda function or how to change the line with the lambda function so that the memory error goes away. Thank you for any help as I'm still learning python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming cdata.Date is a Pandas Series, your lambda function *should* *not* return a Series.  See the examples [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html#pandas.Series.apply).  The reason is that the apply() method is being applied to each element, and you don't want to make each row into a separate column (Series).  That's probably the issue that's causing your out-of-memory error.

As for what you *actually* want to do, you should probably be calling the Dataframe.apply() method instead of the Series.apply().  See [these examples](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas.DataFrame.apply).

In general, be clear whether you're operating on a Series or Dataframe, and make sure you're referencing the correct set of docs.

Answer (score 1):

One of this advices could help:

- Try use named function instead lambda
- Try use transform instead apply
- Try use [pandas.Series.str](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html)

Something like this may help:

```
import numpy as np

data[['year','month', 'day']] = np.vstack(cdata.Dates.astype(str).str.split('-'))
```